# How do i change the dataGridView1 size automatic according to the height/number of rows?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code where i add rows:

```
void PopulateApplications()
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();            
            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 1)
                {
                    var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName);
                    ima = icon.ToBitmap();
                    ima = resizeImage(ima, new Size(25, 25));
                    ima.Save(@"c:\temp\ima.jpg");
                    String status = p.Responding ? "Running" : "Not Responding";
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(ima,p.ProcessName, status);
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the result:

[image]

I want that the gray area under the columns and rows not to be display only the columns/rows.
Maybe i need to resize also the form1 and also the dataGridView1 ? And to resize it each time a new row is added.

What should i do with this gray area ?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, you can change that gray to white like this `dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = Color.White`

Comment: I have the same problem. I shrinked it so only the column header was visible and every time I add a row I make the `dataGridView1.Height += size;` where size is the height of a row. Don't forget to check if the height is bigger then the size of the form.

Comment: Georgi what i did now is to color all the background in white. Then the columns 2 and 3 colored with LightGoldenrodYellow. Then i know now for sure that in the beginning there are like 5 to 7 processes/apss running already as default. So in form1 resize event i added a label checked the dize and changed it in my case to: 648,354 / Now the user can change the size of the form manualy just like in the Windows Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
 dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode =DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```

However consider that this snippet will change the row height of your row according to the rows count, to fit the the Height of Grid. I don't Know if you want such a behaviour.

In order to get the expected result you can calculate  each row height, every time:

```
int height = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
    height += row.Height;
}
height += dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight;
```

And then set :

```
dataGridView1.Height=height;
```

However, I have to admit I haven't test this.....

**EDIT :**

```
void PopulateApplications()
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear(); 
            dataGridView1.Height=0;
            dataGridView1.Height += dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight;           
            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 1)
                {
                    var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName);
                    ima = icon.ToBitmap();
                    ima = resizeImage(ima, new Size(25, 25));
                    ima.Save(@"c:\temp\ima.jpg");
                    String status = p.Responding ? "Running" : "Not Responding";
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(ima,p.ProcessName, status);
                    dataGridView1.Height+=22;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ok i know the row height it's 22. How do i check in my method PopulateApplications in my question that if a new row have been added then resize grow the form by 22 height ? Since my method PopulateApplications is called from a timer it will be update each 5 seconds. So i need to check inside the method if a new row was added then resize the form1 height by 22.